# Add Custom Values not in table?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Table Location has the values

- New York
- Oregon
- Missouri
- California
- Colorado

`var location = (from loc in Locations select (loc));`

I get:

- New York
- Oregon
- Missouri
- California
- Colorado

What do I need to do if I wanted to add a value not in that table (i.e. "Not Found")

Comment: You are just trying to add a value to `location`?

Comment: Are you trying to add values in the table, or you want something like you do a select if not found display a default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(from loc in Locations select loc)
    .Concat(from loc in new[] { "Not Found" } select loc);
```

Or, in the other syntax:

```
Locations.Concat(new[] { "Not Found" });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var location = (from loc in Locations select (loc)).FirstOrDefault();
```

That will give you the null default that you can handle into displaying "NotFound".

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
location.ToList().Add(new Location() { LocationId = 0, Name = "Not Found"});
```